# How to search for divs matching two attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of `div` elements with the class "row" and attributes `data-date-month` and `data-date-day`.

I'm looking to count the number of elements with the class `row` whose attributes match today's day and month.

As far as I'm aware, to search for all the `div` elements matching the month is as follows:

```
function calculateStats(){      
    var d = new Date();
    var tmon = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var tday = d.getDate();
    var numMatches = $('div.row[data-date-month="' + tmon + '"]').length;
}
```

The only way I understand how to accomplish this is by using `$.each()`:

```
var numMatches = 0;
$('div.row[data-date-month="' + tmon + '"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('data-date-day') == tday) 
        numMatches++;
});
```

However, this is a very intensive function when there could potentially be hundreds of elements to scan through.

How can I search efficiently to find elements that match the day as well, or do I have to use `$.each()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two attribute selectors, like this:

```
var numMatches = $('div.row[data-date-month="' + tmon + '"][data-date-day="' + tday + '"]').length;
```

Alternatively, you can use `filter()`:

```
var numMatches = $('div.row').filter(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    return $el.data('date-month') == tmon && $el.data('date-day') == tday;
}).length;
```

Comment: Perfect answer - I didn't realise you could stack attribute selectors. I'd considered `filter()` too but assumed it would be more taxing - which is going to be more efficient?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I would guess that `filter()` would be quicker.

Comment: Well. you are going to be quering the dom once for `div.row` and then looping again on the array to filter it down. Assuming sizzle/jquery doesn't do something more expensive internally, filter would be more expensive

Comment: That's true however attribute selectors are relatively expensive. It would depend on jQuery's caching of the object Vs the attribute selector. I'm tempted to setup a jsperf to test it :)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 what's cool about attribute selectors is that they're available in all modern web, and even kinda supported in IE8. Also @rory-mccrossan it looks like attribute selectors might be faster http://jsperf.com/jquery-filter-vs-attribute-selector

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Even with [multiple attribute selectors](http://jsperf.com/jquery-filter-vs-attribute-selector/2) filter is slower. I obviously had too much faith in it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery `.filter()` method:

```
var numMatches = $('div.row').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('date-month') == tmon && $(this).data('date-day') == tday;
}).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .length to count elements

```
$(".row[data-date-month = '" + tmon + "'][data-date-day = '" + tday + "']").length
```